# Is it legal to invite a friend to my Google family

Tags: google-account, google-play-family

I would like to invite a friend to my Google family cause there is a song or two she would like to listen to and I am thinking about buying a few movies on that Google account too so I am wondering if I can do that legally without getting into trouble with the law

Comment: Oh, and I forgot to mention I bought the two songs with Google play rewards credits